# Node.js UDP Stream

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, udp

Im trying to "port" some code from PHP into Node and im struggling to find out how to get it working. Im trying too connect to an RCON server over UDP.
Here is a simplified version of the PHP version which works:

```
$address = '1.2.3.4:1234';
$password = 'password';

$socket = stream_socket_client('udp://' . $address, $errno, $errstr);
stream_set_blocking($socket, 0);

$loginRequest = chr(0x45) . $password;
stream_socket_sendto($socket, $loginRequest, 0, $address);
echo 'RCON Login Request Sent' . PHP_EOL;
echo $loginRequest . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;

do {
    $data = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, 127, 0, $address);
} while (!$data);
echo 'RCON Received Response' . PHP_EOL;
echo $data . PHP_EOL;
```

Here is what I have got in Node, which doesnt seem to do anything. I dont even get any acknowledgment of a connection from the server.

```
var address = '1.2.3.4';
var port = '1234';
var password = 'password';

var socket = require('dgram').createSocket('udp4');

socket.on('message', function (msg, from) {
    console.log(msg);
});

socket.on('listening', function () {
    var loginPacket = new Buffer(String.fromCharCode(0xff) + password);
    socket.send(loginPacket, 0, loginPacket.length, port, address, function (err, bytes) {
        console.log('packet sent');
    });
});

socket.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err);
});

socket.bind(0);
```

Any help with this would be great! maca134

Comment: Nitpick: UDP is not connection-oriented and is not a stream in the sense that TCP is a stream.

Comment: The default encoding for passing a string to the `Buffer` constructor is not `binary`, so you need to pass `binary` as the encoding: `new Buffer('\xFF' + password, 'binary')`. The first `0xFF` byte causes issues with the default `utf8` encoding. Also, another difference is you're using `0xFF` in node whereas you're using `0x45` in PHP.

Comment: i replaced the buffer quickly, i have some other code to create the packet the is to be sent.

Comment: @mscdex: Thank you very much, I had the same problem and passing "binary" as the encoding to my `Buffer` object fixed it. If you'd like to post this as an answer I'll happily upvote it as many times as I can! (i.e. once :) )

Answer (score 1):

The default encoding for passing a string to the `Buffer` constructor is not `binary`, so you need to pass binary as the encoding: `new Buffer('\xFF' + password, 'binary')`. The first 0xFF byte causes issues with the default `utf8` encoding. Also, another difference is you're using `0xFF` in node whereas you're using `0x45` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.bind` takes a port and optional host.  You're supplying port 0.

I'm not sure which port you want to listen on but for sake of example I'll use 888.

```
socket.bind(888);
```

Comment: In their example it would be `socket.bind(1234, '1.2.3.4');`

Comment: Binding to a random port yields the result unfortunately.